# Run command on remote host after org-publish

Tags: org-export, ssh, org-publish

I try to setup a basic, easy website workflow. Right now I can simply press `C-e P x project-name`, export and upload my Org, image, and whatnot files as HTML.
As I don't want to upload that directly into `/var/www`, because you'd need special permissions, I want to run a command right after publishing on my webserver.

Is there a more elegant (better: more robust) way of solving the issue, besides running some kind of command/script after `org-publish`?

I tried to do that via inotify/a random inotify script I found on SO, but it won't recognize the changes I made, poor inotify script. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566569/how-to-continuously-monitor-the-directory-using-dnotify-inotify-command). I'm pretty sure the Apache log example is close to what you want. So this would be something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
while inotifywait -e modify <your-export-directory>; do
  # do something...
  cp -r <your-export-directory> /var/www
  # ...or other
done
```